# NetBeans html javabeans

Tags: java, html, netbeans, javabeans

Trying to make a site with an intro and then a second page with some calculation between two input fields.

Before now, I've only used managed beans on the index, and when I try to reference the bean on the second page, it's not receiving.

```html
<h:body>
        <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <h:outputLabel value="What is the bill of sale?"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{taxBean.sale}"/>
                
                <h:outputLabel value="What State are you in?"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{taxBean.state}" size="2"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            
            <h:commandButton value="#{taxBean.calc()}">Submit/>
            </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

The text after value looks like normal quote text, instead of a declaration.

How do I make the bean reference on the second page work? Is there an option for the bean to point to the second page, or some code I need to put on the page itself?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do I make the bean reference on the second page work? Is there an option for the bean to point to the second page, or some code I need to put on the page itself?

Comment: OK, update your post to show that.